# How to close the on-screen list of process

Tags: nexus-7

My kids played with my Nexus 7 and since then, I have a list of what I think is process on the upper right corner of the screen.

The first line is three numbers, like 4.38 / 4.7 / 4.77 and a colored bar.

And then, a list of process(?)
com.android.systemui
system_server
mpdecision
...
How can I close all that ?

Comment: Hi, Can you go to `Settings > Developer Options` there are a few things there that could be responsible. They all start with "show ... Something" e.g. `Show hardware layers updates` and `Show GPU view updates` and so on. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: The problem is that I dont have anything like Developper Options in the settings menu, even in the more.. sub-menu

Comment: OK, I found the answer: tap "build number" 7 times to become a developer!!!
bordel...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your hunch is correct - it's basically a small process monitor. Go to Settings -> Developer Options and uncheck the setting labelled "Show CPU Usage" to disable it.